# Performing server side operations in ag-grid with elasticsearch as database

Tags: elasticsearch, ag-grid-react

I am trying to use ag-grid in my web application. The data which I want to display is in elastic search.

Can anyone tell how to perform server side operations with elastic search as database.

Comment: Have you done any research? Have you tried anything? Please share your efforts.